# how to send sms from web application to mobile in php in india

Tags: php, asp-classic

### ** > how to send sms from web application to mobile in php **

I want to any one wist my site and sent the contacts information in my mobile. how it possible.  2. how i get mobile operator types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Twilio Api for sending sms in India

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sms service providers.

Try some free demo and go for appropriate.

Eg. smsgatewayhub

Comment: If it is useful information for you, mark it as useful